# What issue sending to the Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I started receiving a message from the Graph website that says "We had an issue sending this request to the Graph API. For assistance, connect with us on StackOverflow with the tag [microsoftgraph]."

Kept trying and no change.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders

A list of my mail folders.  I was getting them earlier today.  Now I get the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it has nothing to do with the query itself, just stumbled upon the same error while executing the simple query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/`

**Root cause**

Turns out when `History log` reaches certain size (in my case it was more than `2400`log entries),  the error started to appear no matter what the query is submitted.

It is browser specific issue related with *Local Storage limit*, once the size of History log (which is stored in Local Storage) reaches this limit, the error started to appear.

Per Chrome [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage)

> APIs like Local Storage and Session Storage, which still has a limit of **5 MB** per origin

**How to resolve it?**

One option to circumvent this error would be to **clear history log**:

- under History panel click `Show More` link and dialog will appear
- click `Remove All` button to clear history log

That's it, the specified error should no longer occur.

[image]

And last but not least, the issue [has been also reported](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer/issues/260) in `microsoft-graph-explorer` repository